# Can't pull on Xcode Source Control (Repository is Locked)

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

Me and my teammates are having a hard time trying to fix an issue with source control and we don't know how to fix it.

What happened:

1. I had to change the bundle identifier to be able to build on a phone
2. I had to change the .plist file for google Firebase because of the bundle id change
3. I made a commit and pushed the project to our repository in Bitbucket and pushed it

Now when they try to pull the latest change they all get the files but with merge issues (That don't reflect on the source control screen) and when you check on the log it doesn't show that they were able to pull the commit (even though they got the files and all the files even have the head and MASTER text that shows up when you have merge issues). The error we keep getting is

> "The repository is locked."
>
> "Make sure any other operations on the repository are finished and try again. "

I tried checking the other questions but the same error only shows up for users that can't commit because the repository is locked. Not while pulling.

Comment: "I tried checking the other questions but the same error only shows up for users that can't commit because the repository is locked. Not while pulling." I don't see what difference that makes. A locked repository is a locked repository. Remove the lock, as the answer to the "other questions" explain. — And please, stop using Xcode's built-in git "support". It's broken. Real git users use the Terminal, or at least something like Sourcetree.

Comment: @matt That's the problem there is no lock.